# MySQL - getting SUM of MAX results from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, select, join

Here's my problem:
I have 2 identical tables (past month data, current month data) - data_2010_03, data_2010_04:

```
Content_type (VARCHAR), content_id (INT), month_count (INT), pubDate (DATETIME)
```

Data in month_count is updated hourly, so for each combination of `content_type` and `content_id` we insert new row, where value of `month_count` is incrementally updated.

Now I try something like this:
`SELECT MAX(t1.month_count) AS max_1, MAX(t2.month_count) AS max_2, SUM(max_1 + max_2)  AS result, t1.content_type, t1.content_id

FROM data_2010_03 AS t1

JOIN data_2010_04 AS t2 ON t1.content_type = t2.content_type AND t1.content_id = 
t2.content_id

WHERE t2.pubDate < '2010-04-08' AND t1.content_type = 'video'

GROUP BY t1.content_id

ORDER BY result desc, max_1 desc, max_2 desc

LIMIT 0,10`

I get an error "Unknown column 'max_1' in 'field list'. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use aliases in expressions (on the same level of select) so

```
SUM(max_1 + max_2) AS result
```

has to be written as

```
MAX(t1.month_count)+MAX(t2.month_count) AS result
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
SELECT MAX(t1.month_count) AS max_1, MAX(t2.month_count) AS max_2, SUM(max_1 + max_2) AS result
```

Can you just do

```
SELECT MAX(t1.month_count) + MAX(t2.month_count) AS result
```

Or I may have misunderstood the requirement.